# Adding two integers without using plus operator

Tags: c, addition

I found a source code in C language. I take from here :[link:](http://0x2013.blogspot.com/2013/06/c-menambah-integer-tanpa-menggunakan.html)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,hasil;
    printf("Masukan integer pertama: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Masukan integer kedua: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    hasil = a - ~b -1;
    printf("Hasil tambah kedua-dua integer :%d",hasil);
    return 0;
}
```

Seem, the code don't use `"+"` or `"- -"` operation to add thus two integers.
Can anybody tell me, what are this technique or concept be used?

Comment: This relies on the representation of integers being [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That's true of most modern computers but is not required by the standard.

Answer (score 6):

This "technique" is a brain teaser. As far as the practical use goes, it is about as useless as it gets: all it does is computing negative `b` in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) without using unary minus:

```
-b == (~b + 1)
a+b == a - (-b) == a - (~b + 1) == a - ~b - 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

An addition is replaced with subtraction here: `a + b = a - (-b)`. Since in most current processors (at least in all I am aware of) negative integers are represented as a two's complement, `-b = ~b + 1` (bitwise NOT and then plus 1). Hence, `a + b = a - (~b + 1) = a - ~b - 1`.

Comment: Unfortunately this has one broken corner case: `b==INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
hasil = a - ~b -1;
```

is the magic. The code assumes that signed integers are represented using [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation, which is overly popular nowadays. One property of this representation is that if interpreted as unsigned (as a raw bit pattern, how the `~` operator treats it), negative numbers are represented as `(1 << bitwidth) - n`, where `n` is the absolute value of the negative number, and `bitwidth` is the number of bits in an `int`.

This essentially results in the fact that bitwise NOT-ing a number `k` transforms it to `- k - 1`, so `a - (~b) - 1` is just `a - (-b - 1) - 1 = a + b`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone once designed a processor that only implemented the subtract instruction, which was a little more elegant than the referenced code.

The code

```
c = a - ~b - 1;
```

is a slightly over complex way of saying

```
c = a - -b;
```

and moreover requires 2's complement arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>


unsigned int f (unsigned int a , unsigned int b);


unsigned int f (unsigned int a , unsigned int b)

{

   return a ?   f ( (a&b) << 1, a ^b) : b;

}


int main()

{


int a = 9;

int b = 7;


int c = f(a,b);

printf("Sum = %d", c);

getch();

return 0;


}
```

---

Output: Sum = 16

---